# What is an (M) H30 with four pins?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I would like to find a replacement for the component labeled (M)H30 (top in the pictures). The pictures show a circuit board of a WH-1000XM4 headphone (A-5020-595-A, Sub-R). The headphones can no longer be charged. Sweat has probably penetrated and turned the connection pin into verdigris. Otherwise the headphones worked until the battery was empty. Unfortunately I don't have a circuit diagram. Regarding the size: The square Atmel lower to the H30 is approx. 5mm x 5mm. What is an H30? How is it specified?

[image: board before cleaning]

[image: and after]

Comment: It looks like a Microchip MIC5302 except it's a leaded package, not leadless

Answer (score 4):

The manufacturer is [MinebeaMitsumi](https://nmbtc.com/) and the package is SC-82AB. We can see that the marking style matches from pictures on their homepage:

[image]

(Source: [nmbtc.com](https://nmbtc.com/product-category/reset-ics/))

There is also [this thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/178k4og/what_part_is_this_looks_like_its_manufactured_by/) that says the logo on the IC is Mitsumi's old logo.

Since MinebeaMitsumi doesn't specify markings in their datasheets and they have about 20 different ICs in the SC-82AB package (mainly LDO regulators and reset ICs), I think the only way to identify this chip is by contacting them.